# Assigning array carrying a reference to a new array permits writing to the reference without accessing the original variable assigned to the reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference, copy, copy-assignment

```
$a = [1 => "A"];
$b = &$a[1];
$c = $a; 
$c[1] = "C";
echo $a[1];
```

Output : `C` (But I am expecting the output to be `A`)

Apparently, array is not referenced by `=` sign.

`$c = $a;` <- this should make a copy of `$a` and assign it to `$c`, but why does reference take place here?

Moreover, if we simply remove the second line (`$b = &$a[1];`), or replace it with (`$b = &$a;`), it behaves as expected.

Any explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: [PHP References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 : Sorry, that doesn't seem to answer my question. I know how references work in php.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet demonstrates that there are two ways to access a reference.

The `$b` variable offers a mechanism to access, modify, and destroy the reference.

The copy of the reference held in `$c` can be accessed and modified, but the reference itself cannot be destroyed via `unset()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MOsRC))

```
$a = [1 => "A"];
$b = &$a[1];
$c = $a; 

var_dump($c);    // array(1) { [1]=> &string(1) "A" }

unset($c[1]);    // does not affect the reference

var_dump($c);    // array(0) { }

var_dump($a);    // array(1) { [1]=> &string(1) "A" }

unset($b);       // now the reference is destroyed

var_dump($a);    // array(1) { [1]=> string(1) "A" }
```